Birt report from eclispe is not showing all the lines
I have a BIRT report in Eclipse that utilizes three datasets from a CSV datasource. The datasets are handover_formData Set, handover_otroColums, and DataSet_do_tempj5. Each dataset has distinct fields. When I run the report and view it in the web viewer, only one record from handover_formData Set is displayed. However, when I preview the handover_formData Set dataset individually, it shows 27 records.
I am using eclispe:
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200
I don't have any idea what's happened.
There are no filters applied.
The CSV files are intact, all the fields are correct in a file. (there is no null values or something like that)
Could you help me to show all the records please?




show all the records from BIRT report

You did not show the layout structure and the bindings.
